# What are advantages of pattern matching over conditionals in FP (in layman's terms)?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, pattern-matching, conditional-statements

In **layman's terms**, what exactly are the benefits of pattern matching, other than historical reasons? The answers I came across are mostly beyond my level (e.g I don't understand what heap allocation has to do with this).

I have a background in Python, only recently picking up Haskell again.

So I had a hard time understanding other answers given in the context of other languages.

Comment: What is the answer you came across?

Comment: [A Crossroad at A Branch](http://www.vex.net/~trebla/haskell/crossroad.xhtml)

Comment: @DanielWagner Thanks! V. nice link

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I cannot find the exact link I referred to in my qu, but I'd also looked at: https://www.reddit.com/r/elixir/comments/34jyto/what_are_the_benefits_of_pattern_matching_as/

Comment: I also recommend to read about [boolean blindness](https://existentialtype.wordpress.com/2011/03/15/boolean-blindness/).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One of the most useful aspects of using pattern matching instead of conditionals is to allow APIs involving only *total* operations, i.e. operations which never cause runtime exceptions / errors.

Consider this code, exploiting an hypothetical function `runOperationOn`, returning `Maybe String`.

```
case runOperationOn someData of
   Just res -> putStrLn ("The operation was successful: " ++ res)
   Nothing  -> putStrLn "The operation failed!"
```

Here, pattern matching allows to check whether the operation succeeded and get the result on success, *at the same time*. The last part is crucial. Using booleans, we would need to use something like:

```
if canRunOperationOn someData
then putStrLn ("The operation was successful: " ++ doRunOperationOn someData)
else putStrLn "The operation failed!"
```

This looks similar, but it has significant drawbacks compared to pattern matching:

- It splits the functionality into two functions: one to check if we can perform the operation, and one to actually do it.
- It involves a *partial* function `doRunOperationOn` which returns a `String`, but will crash on invalid inputs.

The latter is quite bad, since it puts some burden on the programmer, who has to remember to ask "can I?", or risk a crash.